# kotlin 'onClick' overrides nothing

Tags: kotlin

```
override fun onClick(view: View) {
        when(view.id){
            R.id.option1_text -> selectedOptionStyle(binding.option1Text, 1)
            R.id.option2_text -> selectedOptionStyle(binding.option2Text, 2)
            R.id.option3_text -> selectedOptionStyle(binding.option3Text, 3)
            R.id.option4_text -> selectedOptionStyle(binding.option4Text, 4)
        }
    }
```

how to solve it

I don't know what's the problem

Comment: could you please provide the full snippet of the class where you override `onClick`?

Comment: You can also try to debug `view.id` debug and compare with all IDs which you are using.